# How do I auto adjust the numbering in citations?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

I am writing a report with a number of citations that are continuously being updated. I typically use \bibitem for my bibliography. But I am unable to auto adjust the numbering of these through the document, I would like them to appear as [1], [2],....[5] etc. Currently [5] appears in chapter 1 whereas [1] is in the next section. Is there a way to adjust this using bibitem? I use OVERLEAF.

I am new to .bib files but I tried the .bib file but i got no output from it for some reason. I use Zotero as my library and i extracted the bib file from there.  I can link the literature through the `\cite` command, for eg `\cite{google}` but it appears as [google] in the text with the bibliography not being printed at the end with the print biblio command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1
Here is what I have tried. In my document, before the `\begin{document}` line, I used

```
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
  \bibliography{Phd.bib}
 \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

Just at the end where I need the bibliography to appear I used `\printbibliography`.

The Phd.bib file contains one item for now, just to test.

```
@article{pant, title={Influence of oxide films on primary water stress corrosion cracking initiation of alloy 600}, 
 volume={348}, ISSN={00223115},
 DOI={10.1016/j.jnucmat.2005.10.002}, 
 abstr number={1–2}, 
 journal={Journal of Nuclear Materials}, 
 author={Panter, J. and Viguier, B. and Cloué, J.-M. and Foucault, M. and Combrade, P. and Andrieu, E.}, 
 year={2006}, 
 month={Jan}, 
 pages={213–221}, }
```

I use `\cite{pant}` which ends up as [pant] on my pdf and no bibliography printed. I use overleaf so I am not sure how to individually run bibtex?

Comment: BibTeX is designed for this.  Have the references in the bib file.  tex file with `\cite`s must define `\bibliographystyle` and later invoke `\bibliography` with your bib file as the argument.  Typically, compile document once, run BibTeX, then compile document two more times.  The blg file is the log file that tells you if BibTeX succeeded.  The bbl file is the file containing the bibitem like output of BibTeX.  If you change data in the bib file, you will need to redo BibTeX to incorporate it.

Comment: `biblatex` and `bibtex` are two different programs.  I have experience with the latter, but not the former.  I am sorry I misunderstood the question

Comment: If bibtex works fine, i could use it. I have never used either before and just \bibitem. So if you could help with that while using zotero and overleaf, i'd be thankful.

Comment: The code currently shown in the question is a mixture of `biblatex` and BibTeX code. If you want to use `biblatex`, remove the `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` and replace `\bibliography{Phd.bib}` with `\addbibresource{Phd.bib}`. Your document will need to be compiled with Biber, but Overleaf will do that automatically (thanks to `latexmk`). If things don't work at first, try clearing the cache and recompile: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache. If the wrong output persist, have a look at the `.log` and `.blg` files.